# Not able to get value of SearchView on BackPress in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, searchview

I am working on a functionality in which I am fetching customers data from API. And I also have a `SearchView` in my Fragment.

Now the problem is, when I enter a text in `SearchView` and then hit search button then it shows me list of filtered customers and after that if I select one the customer and go to detail page and after that I press back from detail page then `SearchView` has the text I entered earlier but *I am not getting data according to search. I am getting list of all customers as search field is empty in params.*

What can I do?

Snippet:

```
  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (searchView.getQuery().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.name_blank_caution, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                AdvisorListApi();
                searchView.clearFocus();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**And in params**

```
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("api_token", user.get("api_token"));
    params.put("user_id", user.get("id"));
    params.put("prefer", searchingCriteria.get("prefer"));
    params.put("financial_concern", searchingCriteria.get("financial_concern"));
    params.put("search_name", searchView.getQuery().toString());
    params.put("sort_by", sort_by);
    params.put("contacted", contacted);
    params.put("non_contacted", non_contacted);
    params.put("blocked", blocked);
```

Comment: probably you can try to use `searchView.getText()` instead of `searchView.getQuery()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can again call the API in onResume() method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AdvisorListApi();
    }
```

or else you can clear the text in SearchView.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    searchView.setQuery("", false);
    }
```